# different results from awk and grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep

This gives result 124:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","; count = 0}; { if ($7 ~ /Nature Life/) { count++ }} END   {print count}' file.csv
```

This gives result 123:

```
grep -cE '^([^,]*,){6}[^,]*Nature Life' file.csv
```

The file is too large to read.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: A shot in the dark: check if last line matches and if there is a new line at the end of the last line.

Comment: If there are only 123 matching lines you might be able to print them and diagnose by hand

Comment: Testing gives the same count. But that is assuming the real data. Could you provide some lines of the file to test.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the inconstancy, the following should reveal the one line that the awk is catching that the grep is not:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}$7~/Nature Life/' file.csv | grep -vE '^([^,]*,){6}[^,]*Nature Life'
```

The objective here is to print everything the awk sees and then filter out everything that the grep sees (grep -v). The likelihood is that your grep's regex is not 100% what you're looking for.

Comment: The `grep -v` to find the odd line is clever, but your statement about not using `;` after a BEGIN block is false/irrelevant; it makes no difference to the running of the `awk` script.

Comment: You're right I shouldn't have said that. Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For GNU `grep` at least, in a UTF-8 locale `,[^,]*,` will not match `,something,` if `something` contains sequences of bytes that don't form [valid characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247731).

For instance:

```
$ printf '1,\200,3,4,5,6,Nature Life,8\n' |
   grep -cE '^([^,]*,){6}[^,]*Nature Life'
0
```

While, for awk field splitting, it does not matter:

```
$ printf '1,\200,3,4,5,6,Nature Life,8\n' | awk -F, '$7 ~ /Nature Life/'
1,�,3,4,5,6,Nature Life,8
```

Run `grep` under `LC_ALL=C` to avoid issues with text in the wrong encoding (as long as the string to search and the separator (`,`) are in ASCII).

```
$ printf '1,\200,3,4,5,6,Nature Life,8\n' |
   LC_ALL=C grep -cE '^([^,]*,){6}[^,]*Nature Life'
1
```