# How to create string with invalid unicode characters, in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, unicode

For some testing purposes I need a string with invalid unicode characters. How to create such string in Zsh?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you mean UTF-8 encoded Unicode characters.

That depends what you mean by *invalid*.

```
invalid_byte_sequence=$'\x80\x81'
```

That's a sequence of bytes that, by itself, isn't valid in UTF-8 encoding (the first byte in a UTF-8 encoded character always has the two highest bits set). That sequence could be seen in the middle of a character though, so it could end-up forming a valid sequence once concatenated to another invalid sequence like `$'\xe1'`. `$'\xe1'` or `$'\xe1\x80'` themselves would also be invalid and could be seen as a truncated character.

```
other_invalid_byte_sequence=$'\xc2\xc2'
```

The 0xc2 byte would start a 2-byte character, and 0xc2 cannot be in the middle of a UTF-8 character. So that sequence can never be found in valid UTF-8 text. Same for `$'\xc0'` or `$'\xc1'` which are bytes that never appear in the UTF-8 encoding.

For the `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` sequences, I assume the current locale's encoding is UTF-8.

```
non_character=$'\ufffe'
```

That's one of the 66 currently specified [non-characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Non-characters).

```
not_valid_anymore=$'\U110000'
```

Unicode is now restricted to code points up to 0x10FFFF. And the UTF-8 encoding which was originally designed to cover up to 0x7FFFFFFF (`perl` also supports a variant that goes to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) is now conventionally restricted to that as well.

```
utf16_surrogate=$'\ud800'
```

Code points 0xD800 to 0xDFFF are code points reserved for the UTF16 encoding. So the UTF-8 encoding of those code points is invalid.

Now most of the remaining code points are still not assigned in the latest version of Unicode.

```
unassigned=$'\u378'
```

Newer versions of Unicode come with new characters specified. For instance Unicode 8.0 (released in June 2015) has  ([U+1F917](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f917/index.htm)) which was not assigned in earlier versions.

```
unicode_8_and_above_only=$'\U1f917'
```

Some testing with `uconv`:

```
$ printf %s $invalid_byte_sequence| uconv -x any-name
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 0. Bytes: 80 Error: Illegal character found
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 1. Bytes: 81 Error: Illegal character found
$ printf %s $other_invalid_byte_sequence| uconv -x any-name
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 0. Bytes: c2 Error: Illegal character found
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 1. Bytes: c2 Error: Truncated character found
$ printf %s $non_character| uconv -x any-name
\N{<noncharacter-FFFE>}
$ printf %s $not_valid_anymore| uconv -x any-name
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 0. Bytes: f4 90 80 80 Error: Illegal character found
$ printf %s $utf16_surrogate | uconv -x any-name
Conversion to Unicode from codepage failed at input byte position 0. Bytes: ed a0 80 Error: Illegal character found
$ printf %s $unassigned | uconv -x any-name
\N{<unassigned-0378>}
$ printf %s $unicode_8_and_above_only | uconv -x any-name
\N{<unassigned-1F917>}
$
```

With GNU `grep`, you can use `grep .` to see if *it* can find a character in the input:

```
l=(invalid_byte_sequence other_invalid_byte_sequence non_character
  not_valid_anymore utf16_surrogate unassigned unicode_8_and_above_only)
for c ($l) print -r ${(P)c} | grep -q . && print $c
```

Which for me gives:

```
non_character
not_valid_anymore
utf16_surrogate
unassigned
unicode_8_and_above_only
```

That is, my `grep` still considers some of those invalid, non-characters or not-assigned-yet characters as being (or containing) characters. YMMV for other implementations of `grep` or other utilities.

Comment: What shell is that `for c ($l) print -r ${(P)c} |`

Comment: @1_CR, well the question is quite explicit which shell we're talking of here as it's in the subject, body and tags.